# How to parse "I get ready for school"?

Tags: meaning

> ***I get ready for school.***

Does it mean:

> I get ready and I am going to go to school.

or

> I get ready for going to school.   It means that I make preparation for going to school.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

In this case "get" means "become".

"get ready" is a stable phrase that means "make yourself prepared".
For example, you can tell your friend: "We are leaving in 5 minutes. Get ready."

If you want to specify the target of preparation, you use "for".
For example: "The football match is about to begin! Get ready for the action!"

The present simple tense ("I get ready") means you are simply describing what you usually do on any typical day. As opposed to present continuous ("I'm getting ready") in which case you are describing your activity at this very moment.

Combining all this together we get:

"I get ready for school."
~
"I do whatever preparations are needed to become ready for school." -- this may include taking shower, doing homework, getting dressed, packing the backpack etc.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is closest. It means that you are preparing for everything that "school" entails: going to school, doing work at school, having lunch at school, etc.

Answer (score 0):

'I get ready for school' is in the simple present, which is not the most common tense. One area of life where it is used all the time is sports commentary, so you are providing a commentary on yourself.

Comment: It may not be most common tense, but the implication that it is just used for commentary goes a bit far, I think. (Here, I wrote "I think" - and I am not providing any commentary on my actions!)

Answer (score 0):

The second one, even though it is using basic, rough English is correct.

"I get ready for school."(better worded "I am getting ready for school.") means that the implied person is in the process of getting ready to go to school.